# How can I specify a Qmake file during packaging?

Tags: packaging, qt

I'm trying to package a [piece of software](https://github.com/thirtythreeforty/bullycpp/tree/installer) that I wrote for Debian/Ubuntu.  I've read that `dh` supports Qmake natively.  However, my `.pro` file is not in the root directory of the source tree, but rather in `src/`.  Accordingly, `dh_auto_configure` can't find it, and the build process doesn't actually compile anything.

I'm currently using the default `rules` script:

```
DPKG_EXPORT_BUILDFLAGS = 1
include /usr/share/dpkg/default.mk

%:
    dh $@
```

How can I specify the correct `.pro` file for the autoconfiguration step?